# .htaccess accept specific filename

Tags: .htaccess

I have this line in my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+upload
```

This line is necessary for security reasons.

This line blocking me to use the files as `upload_ok.png` or `upload_error.png`.

I want to use any file named `*upload*.png` without 403 redirects

Comment: Please clarify your question. You say the rule is necessary for security, then provide two examples which obviously violate it. What files are you trying to protect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a negative lookahead with `\.png`, like this:

```
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+(?!.*upload.*\.png$)upload
```

This says, match if it looks like `/+upload`, but not if there is a match for `.*upload.*\.png$` (`$` means "end of the string").

Answer (score 0):

You can use `negative lookahed` to skip this rule for `upload_ok.png or upload_error.png`:

```
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+upload(?!_(ok|error)\.png).* /
```